# icCube - how to install a JDK on the server to view the Java ETL

Tags: etl, iccube

icCube version 6.6 supports JAVA ETL views, and according to the [documentation](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/etl_java.php) these need a JDK installed at the server.

I installed (on Windows Server 2016) both JDK SE 8 and 10 (jdk1.8.0_172 and jdk-10.0.1) (10 is the latest version) in c:/Program Files/Java.

But if I want to view the result of the Java ETL view I still get the error message:

> the Java JDK not installed but it's needed

What else need to be done besides installing the JDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icCube Windows .exe is embedding a JRE for the sake of simplicity so I believe you need to change the "JRE Path" as mentioned in this [page](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/configuring_iccube/jre_options.php) to point to the JDK path you want to use instead.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It is exactly that.My ini file only had 4 lines left for the runtime environment:[Java Runtime Environment]
JRE Path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172" 
Main Class=crazydev.iccube.server.IcCubeServer
Maximum Version=any
Minimum Version=1.8
Virtual Machine Parameters=-Xmx4g -DicCube.install="C:\Program Files\icCube\6.6\"